# CEP's sequence detection‏

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing

In developing for Fiware's Proton CEP, I came across an issue with Sequence event detection. I'll take advantage of DoSAttack example project, that comes with the software, to explain the issue.

I make two main changes to an original copy of DoSAttack:

-One is to make ExpectedCrash event have 3 more variables. This way I can log to DoSAttackTRConsumer file the 3 values that triggered it.

-Then I also change the Cardinality Policy of the Agent from Single to Unrestricted. This way the event can be triggered several times in a row, as TrafficReports come in (this may be a source to the issue).

I test this result and I find it works ok. I can see in the log that the values that trigger detection are the sequence of 3 values that arrived just before the event, after the first three events have arrived. 
This, taking into account that the test beeing made on those 3 values still remains the original example test: (TR3.volume>1.50* TR2.volume AND TR2.volume>1.50 * TR1.volume).

The issue arrises if I make the test be just (TR3.volume>1.50* TR2.volume), for example, then CEP doesn't hold TR1 correctly. Now TR1 is the same as TR2, so cep loses "memory" of this value.
Going a step further, I make the test, just the condition (3>2) which is always true and should trigger a detection on any event that arrives. In this case, as events arrive, all TR1, TR2 and TR3 are the same and CEP has no memory of past values, even though the agent is of Type: Sequence.

The desired application would be for the CEP to recieve 22 readings as a sequence of input events and analyse only the 1st, 8th, 15th and 22nd values of this sequence, at each value that enters. But I find I can't make CEP remember the values correctly unless I'm testing all of them explicitly in the Condition view-box.

What would be the correct way to analyse the 1st, 8th, 15th and 22nd values that arrived, evaluating each time a new one arrives?

Here is the specificatin of DoSAttack, after altering it:

```
{"epn":{"events":[{"name":"TrafficReport","attributes":[{"name":"volume","type":"Integer","dimension":0}]},{"name":"ExpectedCrash","attributes":[{"name":"Cost","type":"Double","dimension":0},{"name":"TR1","type":"Integer","dimension":"0"},{"name":"TR2","type":"Integer","dimension":"0"},{"name":"TR3","type":"Integer","dimension":"0"}]}],"epas":[{"name":"IncreasingTraffic","epaType":"Sequence","context":"3MinAfterStartUp","inputEvents":[{"name":"TrafficReport","alias":"TR1","consumptionPolicy":"Consume","instanceSelectionPolicy":"First"},{"name":"TrafficReport","alias":"TR2","consumptionPolicy":"Consume","instanceSelectionPolicy":"First"},{"name":"TrafficReport","alias":"TR3","consumptionPolicy":"Consume","instanceSelectionPolicy":"First"}],"computedVariables":[],"assertion":"3>2","evaluationPolicy":"Immediate","cardinalityPolicy":"Unrestricted","internalSegmentation":[],"derivedEvents":[{"name":"ExpectedCrash","reportParticipants":false,"expressions":{"Cost":"10","TR1":"TR1.volume","TR2":"TR2.volume","TR3":"TR3.volume"}}],"derivedActions":[]}],"contexts":{"temporal":[{"name":"3MinAfterStartUp","type":"TemporalInterval","atStartup":true,"neverEnding":false,"initiators":[],"terminators":[{"terminatorType":"RelativeTime","terminationType":"Terminate","relativeTime":"180000"}]}],"segmentation":[],"composite":[]},"consumers":[{"name":"SysTemCrashConsumer","type":"File","properties":[{"name":"filename","value":"/opt/tomcat10/sample/DoSAttack_PredictedCrash.txt"},{"name":"formatter","value":"json"},{"name":"delimiter","value":";"},{"name":"tagDataSeparator","value":"="},{"name":"SendingDelay","value":"1000"}],"events":[{"name":"ExpectedCrash"}],"actions":[]},{"name":"DoSAttackTRConsumer","type":"File","properties":[{"name":"filename","value":"/opt/tomcat10/sample/DoSAttack_TrafficReport.txt"},{"name":"formatter","value":"json"},{"name":"delimiter","value":";"},{"name":"tagDataSeparator","value":"="},{"name":"SendingDelay","value":"1000"}],"events":[{"name":"TrafficReport"}],"actions":[]}],"producers":[{"name":"TrafficReportFileProducer","type":"File","properties":[{"name":"filename","value":"/opt/tomcat10/sample/DoSAttackScenarioJSON.txt"},{"name":"pollingInterval","value":"1000"},{"name":"sendingDelay","value":"1500"},{"name":"formatter","value":"json"},{"name":"delimiter","value":";"},{"name":"tagDataSeparator","value":"="}],"events":[]}],"actions":[],"name":"DoSAttack"}}
```

The producer file, *DoSAttackScenarioJSON.txt*, is still the original one, unaltered:

```
{"Name":"TrafficReport", "volume":"1000"}
{"Name":"TrafficReport", "volume":"1600"}
{"Name":"TrafficReport", "volume":"2500"}
```

If you do include more values than 3 you can see that the issue propagates.

If you need more information let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In the *Sequence* pattern, the engine looks for event instances that occurred in a particular order. 
In *Sequence (A, B, C)*, the engine looks for three event instances, the first one of type A, the second of type B and the third of type C, where:

```
(A's detection time) <= (B's detection time) AND (B's detection time) <= (C's detection time)
```

Usually in a Sequence pattern, either the event types are different, or there is other condition above the participants events (as in the DoSAttack example).

When you use the same event type in a sequence (e.g., *Sequence(A, A, A)*), then the same event instance can be used in all the three places, since it holds the detection order listed above.

In addition, if you use a *"consumptionPolicy": "Consume"* for a participant event, then after the event was used to detect the pattern, it will not be used for future detections of this pattern.

This is why when you have a *Sequence(A, A, A)* with no condition, and event instance *A1* of type *A* arrives, it causes a pattern detection, and since it has *Consume* policy, it will not be kept for future detections. Later when event *A2* of type *A* arrives, it causes another detection based on *A2* alone.

Also, according to the Sequence built-in condition over the detection time, a sequence of  events can be detected although other events arrived in between.

Please describe the pattern you would like to detect. Maybe you can use a Trend or Aggregate EPA instead.

Comment: The pattern I'd like to detect would be of events of a single type. As they arrive they are analised according to their arrival order. So I'd be analysing the 1st (meaning the last arrived) with the 2nd (the previous one that that arrived, and with other older values as well, always based on their order of arrival. So, as a new event is pushed in, it becomes the last to arrive and the test is performed again. It's similar to a shift register, evaluated at each new item that gets pushed in.

Comment: To be more specific on the test performed, something like: 
[A1.value > (A8.value+A15.value+A22.value)*1.1/3 OR A1.value < (A8.value+A15.value+A22.value)*0.9/3].  So I'm evaluating an upper and lower threshold built from a percentage (10% in this case) of the average of some past values. And, as a new event arrives, the each A's values are shifted and the test performed again.

Comment: I would use the _Aggregate_ pattern, lets call it AVG, to compute the average value (not sure which temporal window it should use, maybe a one that is initiated by _A_ and terminated after some relative time). Then I would use a _Sequence(AVG, A)_ with the condition on the value of both.